# Looking for a better way to do some calculation over pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nested-loops

I have a dataframe with some data:

```
some_data=[{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":5},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":5},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":5,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":5,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":5,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":5},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":5,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":6,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":5},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":5},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":5,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":6,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":5,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":5},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":5,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":5},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":5},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":5},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":5,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":5,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":5,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":6},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":5},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":6},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":5},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":4,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":3},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":0},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":1},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":1,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":0,"score_ft_b":4},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":2,"score_ft_b":2},{"score_ft_a":3,"score_ft_b":1}]
df = pd.DataFrame(some_data)
```

I'm trying to use nested loops to check how many times "score_ft_a" and "score_ft_b" meet certain criteria:

```
for score_a in range(5):
    for score_b in range(5):
        for line in range(0, 5):
            for quarter in (0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75):
                for signal in (1, -1):
                    qty_a += len(
                       df[
                                (
                                 df[f"score_ft_a"]
                                 - score_a
                                 + signal * (line + quarter)
                                 > df[f"score_ft_b"]
                                 - score_b)
                                 ])
                    qty_b += len(
                       df[
                                (
                                 df[f"score_ft_b"]
                                 - score_b
                                 - signal * (line + quarter)
                                 >= df[f"score_ft_a"]
                                 - score_a)
                                 ])
```

However, even a small dataframe like the one shown (543 rows) takes a long time to complete the calculation. I'm pretty sure this has to do with nested loops. I've already tried changing the dtypes to int32 and also using conditionals instead of df.query(), but the code still takes almost 2 seconds.

Can you help me with any ideas to speed up these nested loops evaluations?

Comment: you're right there might be a way to avoid the slow nested loops. I'd like to help, can you explain in words how you want to calculate `qty_a`? is `database` the same as `df` above? Can you think of a simpler example that will be easier to understand for people trying to help?

Comment: Your nested loops end up doing 5*5*5*4*2*2 queries to your DF, that's really a lot of them. And each query has to loop over the whole DF once for the filter, and once more to build the results. It might be worth inverting the logic, looping over the DF once and binning the values into bins that you can later count to produce the histogram-like things you seem to be trying to build.

Comment: for sure! it is a soccer fulltime score data. I'm trying to evaluate how many times the player A (related to score_ft_a) have won a match after he has scored "score_a" goals if I consider a positive or negative handicap (signal * (line + quarter)) to him. 

i.e. score_ft_a = 3, score_ft_b = 2

For a live score scenario of 2x2 (score_a and score_b variables), player A still has 1 goal to score and player B has no more. If I apply a neg handicap of -0.5 goal on player A, he would win this match. So, player A win a certain percentage of matches when it's 2x2. I want to calculate this percent.